# Start an application with a specific window size in a specified position

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do I start an application with a certain windows size an in a certain position? I would like to start it via command line, or by launching the app with a shortcut. In my case it's File Explorer. The solution has to work either for Windows 7 and Windows 10 but it does not have to be the same solution.

Unless absolutely necessary I want to do it without 3rd Party software. The question that is supposed to be a duplicate only received answers for 3rd Party software solutions; the other question specifically asks for a software solution as well, my question does not.

Comment: Does it have to be without 3rd party software or additional tools?

Comment: Why was my question refered to a question that has been closed for reasons that don't apply to my question? I haven't aked for third party software and I would prefere a solution without it!

Comment: @Albin if possible yes!

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because I'm too lazy to research & give details but...  Windows 10 (and I believe windows 7) comes with powershell, and using powershell you can do pretty much anything with .net.  If you really want to avoid using 3rd party solutions then you could write your own powershell script that will do the dirty work for you.  Unless you have programming experience already or have found someone else that's already done it, this might be the more difficult way to go. It's likely you'll expend much less effort using a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Here, this guy has already done some of what you want (manipulating windows).  He's using win32 calls (there might not be .net calls, but that's ok, powershell can do win32 calls also).

https://www.raydbg.com/2017/Call-Native-Win32-API-in-PowerShell/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensive search in [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/windows-10-file-explorer/71ce8b7c-cb6e-4f2c-b0da-79f05840dc9d) [Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop-insiderplat_pc/setting-window-size-and-position/8359bc93-ba41-42c4-b291-db806ef5eb25) and elsewhere reveal no solution within Windows itself. [CmdNow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/#synopsis) is an open source solution freely available, and [ShellFolderFix](https://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html) is available freeware also intended to solve this, until Microsoft provides a solution.

Comment: Thank you I did search for quite a while but I only found solutions that included additional tools/applications. Should I have explicitly written that I did search and didn't find any solution? I thought this is mandatory anyway before posting a question!

Comment: Never hurts to tell folks what you did, and how you did it, in your quest for a solution before you Yelp for Help; in fact, I encourage it. Also wanted to explain why I was deviating from the (entirely legitimate and wholly understandable) no-external-app preference you stated.